# MySQL returning nothing on a very simple query

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `groups_pivot` that has these columns:

```
id, pivot_id, group_id, model, creator_id, updater_id, created_at, updated_at
```

In it I store relationships between different models and `groups`:

```
select * from groups_pivot;

id  pivot_id    group_id    model           creator_id  updater_id  created_at       updated_at
1   1           1           App\Models\User 7           7           8/18/2019 22:09  8/18/2019 22:09
2   2           1           App\Models\User 1           1           8/18/2019 22:09  8/18/2019 22:09
3   3           2           App\Models\User 6           6           8/18/2019 22:09  8/18/2019 22:09
4   4           3           App\Models\User 2           2           8/18/2019 22:09  8/18/2019 22:09
```

But when I run this query in both `Laravel` and `mySQLWorkbench` I get null response:

```
select * from groups_pivot
where model = 'App\Models\User';

09:27:41    select * from groups_pivot where model = 'App\Models\User' LIMIT 0, 1000    0 row(s) returned   0.000 sec / 0.000 sec
```

What kind of magic is this? No errors, no response. I am sure I am having a stupid morning, but I cannot see why it is doing this. Thanks for any suggestions on where to look.

Comment: Trailing spaces or other invisible characters in the models column? What do you get for a predicate of `LIKE '%app%'`? Or perhaps `LIKE 'app%models%user'`?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but no. I checked its content

Comment: Curiously the question nick has linked asserted escaping backslashes is not required for = whereas you assert it is.. are you sure you were using = and not LIKE?

Comment: Nick changed the suggestion after I had answered. using LIKE as he suggests now works. His first post was just suggesting looking for invisible chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about:

```
select * from groups_pivot
where model = 'App\\Models\\User';
```

Backslash is often an escape character and thus requires to be escaped itself to be used.

Comment: Rock'nRoll! Works. Many thanks for the sanity!

Answer (score 0):

Try using double quotes (") instead of an apostrophe (') to delimit your values because otherwise backslash is used to denote an escape character.

Comment: Although it's usually better to keep to the sql standard of using ' to delimit strings and " to denote identifiers, as this makes database skills more transferable between vendors